# How to use External Javascript file in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am trying to convert currency in different formats from this link http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/

I copied the http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/money.js file in my assets/js/ file with a name "converter.js"

I also declared this file in my index.html file:

```
<script src="assets/js/converter.js"></script>
```

now i want to call the `fx.convert(1, {from: "USD", to: "INR"});` function to my home.ts file

which i did like

```
declare var fx;

alert(fx.convert(1, {from: "USD", to: "INR"}));
```

that returns with an error:

```
ERROR Error: fx error
at viewWrappedDebugError (VM263 vendor.js:10180)
at callWithDebugContext (VM263 vendor.js:15482)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (VM263 vendor.js:14755)
at ComponentFactory_.create (VM263 vendor.js:11652)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (VM263 vendor.js:4404)
at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (VM263 vendor.js:11849)
at IonicApp.ngOnInit (VM263 vendor.js:54207)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (VM263 vendor.js:12785)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (VM263 vendor.js:14309)
at checkAndUpdateNode (VM263 vendor.js:14252)
```

How can I achieve this functionality perfectly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First check in source and console whether the file is loaded or not.

Comment: yes the file is loaded it displays the function in the console. this is the output ƒ (obj) {
  return new fxWrapper(obj);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Put the import js in src/index.html header tag, before the build/polyfills.js and build/main.js (they are in body tag);

I created a file src/assets/test.js with a var test, imported in src/index.html and then in src/app/app.component.ts declared declare var test;.

test.js

```
var test = "Hello";
```

index.html

...

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/test.js"></script>
```

...
app.componet.ts

```
declare var test;

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  constructor(private statusbar : StatusBar,  splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
   alert(test);
...
```

Comment: i did the same thing. but i have a function instead of the "test" variable and i need to access the components inside that function.please check this code http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/money.js which is the import.js file in your case