# External widget in Ionic Angular 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, widget

How can I use an external widget like this in an Ionic application?

```
<div id="wg-api-football-standings"
  data-host="v3.football.api-sports.io"
  data-key="Your-Api-Key-Here"
  data-league=""
  data-team=""
  data-season=""
  data-theme=""
  data-show-errors="false"
  data-show-logos="true"
  class="wg_loader">
</div>
<script
  type="module"
  src="https://widgets.api-sports.io/2.0.3/widgets.js">
</script>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i put the script in index.html and put the html snippet in the home . the script is loaded but i dont know what to do next

Comment: Probably a dupe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942654/how-to-use-external-javascript-file-in-ionic-3

Comment: i tried but with no results  , i think the .js module get the html element and populate i dont know how to use it